# What to do about upstart in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, upstart, systemd, mythbuntu

So I have a [Myth]buntu system with master backend that started life as 10.04 and now has risen from 14.04 to 16.04. It is the only Ubuntu system I have and is pretty much ignored until it has a glitch. My other systems all use systemd.

So I'm upgrading mythtv from 0.28 to 0.29, and I seem to have done that but myth-setup has been problematic and now I discover that myth-setup does not stop mythbackend as it claims. Further snooping shows mythbackend running with PPID of 1 while `systemctl status mythbackend` shows `failed (Result: exit-code)`. PID 1 is `/sbin/init` which should be systemd.

Furthermore, the mythbackend is running with arguments from `/etc/init/mythtv-backend.conf` (upstart) which to my understanding had been deprecated in 16.04. Now this leads me to suspect much more is also going on. I have very little understanding of upstart.

So how do I extricate upstart from my newly evolved 16.04, or should I?

Comment: With all those upgrades and subsequent changes along the way I would advise you do a fresh installation rather than trying to remove upstart / init scripts. At least try a live flash drive and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

While Upstarted is deprecated on 16.04, it is also installed and supported. The Q&A [SysV, Upstart and systemd init script coexistence](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867843/sysv-upstart-and-systemd-init-script-coexistence) explains the relationship between Upstart and Systemd on 16.04.

That said, using both `systemd` and `upstart` together causes extra complexity to debug, as you've just run into. If MythTV provides a `systemd` unit file that can be used to manage/stop/start the service, prefer that and delete the Upstart config file you found to avoid confusion. If MythTV does provide a `systemd` unit file, encourage them to do so.

Comment: I removed the '/etc/init/mythtv-backend.conf&.override', but when I boot, I get two mythbackends each with different calling arguments. I was surprised that removing them did not prevent the upstart from starting them. What am I missing?

Comment: Your question was "So how do I extricate upstart from my newly evolved 16.04, or should I?", which has been answered. If you further questions about MythTV, you should ask a new question, and provide the output of `systemctl status '*myth*'`, so the the status of all running Myth-related services is shared.